# How should i apply filter on coin gecko API

Tags: node.js, api, coingecko

I am using Node JS with Coin Gecko API. All are working fine but now i need to add filter in following API' end point on coin gecko. I have checked the documentation as well but unable to find any solution. My issue is when i call

**let data = await CoinGeckoClient.coins.all();**

above API. It gives me all the list of coins but i need to add filter like when user type **B** then i can able to get only **B** related coin list in my response.